# Return Multiple checkbox in AJAX response

Tags: php, ajax, checkbox, responsetext

I have 2 php pages, the Page1 contain (html + javascript + php code), the page2 contain php code only.

so, Inside page1, ther's a dropdown contain many values, if i choose one of them, the AJAX code get value to page2.php like this:

If i replace the checkbox input with a Drop down, the script work perfectly, but in this case, it don't work.

The aim is to display the results of page2 as a checkbox's on page1. 
Any idea?

Page1.php:

HTML CODE:

```
  <select onChange="getdids(this.value)" id="groupSelect" name="groupSelect" >
        <option value="0">xxx</option>
            <option value="1">yyy</option>
            <option value="2">zzz</option>
            <option value="3">vvv</option>
  </select> 

  <input type="checkbox" id="alldids" name="alldids" value="0">did<br>
```

AJAX CODE:

```
  <script>
  function getdids(str)
  {
    if (str=="")
      {
       document.getElementById("alldids").innerHTML="";
       return;
      }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
       {
        document.getElementById("alldids").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
       }
    }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","page1.php?groupName="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
 }


 </script>
```

Page2.php:

PHP CODE:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Get dids</title>
    </head>

    <?php
    require_once('../functions.php');
    include('../variables.php');
    $didGrpName=$_GET['groupName'];
    $didGrpId=GroupId($table_groups,$didGrpName);
    $x=array();
    $x=showDidOfGroup($didGrpId);

    $i=1;
    while($i <= $x[$i]){ ?>
    <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $x[$i]; ?>"><?php echo $x[$i]; ?><br>
    <?php $i++; } ?>

    <body>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: That looks like it should work. What is the question? What part of this does not work?

Comment: i can't see the checkbox in page1

Comment: How can i use Jquery to send and get data from php file? I'm newbie in Jquery and AJAX

Answer (score 0):

You never call `getdids` for your checkbox(es), and the value of a group of checkboxes is more complicated to determine then the value of a (non-multiple) select element.

The algorithm for constructing application/x-www-url-form-encoded data from a checkbox group is:

```
Create an empty array
For each "checkbox" in "group of checkboxes with same name":
    if checkbox.checked:
        append encodeURIComponent(name) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(checkbox.value) to array
JOIN array with "&"
```

Comment: it's not too clear for me, i need just to display the result of page2 as a checkbox on page1, the result of page2 is an array contain Mysql response.